# Limiting Axis with Factors in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to be able to limit a categorical axis and only show the first n factors.  I initially wanted to use the range tool but since that required a Range1d for x_range, I gave up on that.  Here is the basic code I'm starting with:

```
cats = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'cat': cats,
    'y': np.random.randint(100, size=len(cats)),
})

p = figure(x_range=df['cat'])
p.vbar(x='cat', top='y', width=0.9, source=df)

l = layout([[p]])

show(l)
```

It would seem that

`p.x_range = FactorRange(start=0, end=4)`

would show the first 5 factors of whatever that range is, but that's giving me this error:

> RuntimeError: FactorRange.start is a readonly property

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FactorRange` is not configured with a numerical start/end, it is configured with the list of factors you want to see displayed:

```
p.x_range = FactorRange(factors=['A', ...])
```

There is an entire chapter in the User's Guide that covers handling categorical data:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html

Note that if you are *updating* a list of factors after a range already exists (e.g. from a callback or such), you should prefer to set the `factors` property of the existing range, not create an entire new `FactorRange`.

Comment: Thank you.  I should have investigated the documentation more.  On a similar note, is there a way to pass the factor range to the range tool as Range1d?

Comment: I don't believe the two can work together at the moment, a GitHub issue would be appropriate to ask for that feature.